# Why can't I use clSetUserEventStatus() multiple times?

Tags: opencl

If I'm not misunderstanding the [standard](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetUserEventStatus.html), it says that when wishing to reuse a user event this cannot be done and a new event must be created (`clReleaseEvent()` + `clCreateUserEvent()`).

In details:

> `clSetUserEventStatus()` can only be called once to change the execution
> status of event.

Now, for the sake of curiosity: why so? Is it a design decision or is it due to some specific reason that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this restriction is there to protect from a situation in which an OpenCL user event is `CL_COMPLETE`, and then `CL_RUNNING`, and then again `CL_COMPLETE` etc. This can potentially lead to some unforeseen consequences and cause bugs (problems with registered callbacks?).

Comment: I get your point but if this is the reason, why isn't it the same for non-user events? I mean, we can reuse non-user events multiple times without problems...

Comment: You can reuse handle to non-user event (`cl_event`), but the underlying event is not reused. After each OpenCL API call your handle points to different event. However, in case of user-created event you create the underlying event on your own with `clCreateUserEvent`, and that's why the event can be reused. You can still later reuse `cl_event` handle, which you used for user event, after you release the underlying event with `clReleaseEvent`.